# What is the best way to implement a small lookup table in an OpenCL Kernel

Tags: opencl

In my kernel it is necessary to make a large number of random accesses to a small lookup table (only 8 32-bit integers).  Each kernel has a unique lookup table.  Below is a simplified version of the kernel to illustrate how the lookup table is used.

```
__kernel void some_kernel(  
    __global uint* global_table,
    __global uint* X,
    __global uint* Y) {

    size_t gsi = get_global_size(0);
    size_t gid = get_global_id(0);

    __private uint LUT[8]; // 8 words of of global_table is copied to LUT

    // Y is assigned a value from the lookup table based on the current value of X
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Y[i*gsi+gid] = LUT[X[i*gsi+gid]];
    }   
}
```

Because of the small size, I am getting the best performance by keeping the table in the __private memory space.  However, because of the random nature in which the lookup table is accessed, there is still a large performance hit.  With the lookup table code removed (replaced with a simple arithmetic operation, for example), although the kernel would provide the wrong answer, the performance improves by a factor of over 3.

Is there a better way?  Have I overlooked some OpenCL feature that provides efficient random access for very small chunks of memory?  Could there be an efficient solution using vector types?

[edit] Note, that the maximum value of X is 7, but the maximum value of Y is as large as 2^32-1.  In other words, all the bits of the lookup table are being used, so it cannot be packed into a smaller representation.

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding correctly is LUT[] and X[] unique for every single work item?

Comment: Have you tried using `__constant` memory for your look-up tables? GPUs often implement separate caches and memory access pathways for constant memory, for speeding up things like shared look-up tables.

Comment: I did try passing global_table as __constant, but for some reason, it didn't help the performance.  Each kernel operates on an independent section of global_table, X, and Y (depending on the thread ID).

Comment: If that is the case __constant most likely won't help because, at least on most GPUs i've seen, it's basically a small cache for global memory. If each thread reads in different values there is nothing for cache to help.

Comment: Intel's OpenCL guide talks about using "shared local memory" for LUTs.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/accelerate-performance-using-opencl-with-intel-hd-graphics#_Toc357619019  Might be useful in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest solution I can think of is to not use arrays in the first place: use individual variables instead and use some sort of access function to access them as if they were an array. IIRC (at least for the AMD compiler but I'm pretty sure this is true for NVidia as well): generally, arrays are always stored in memory, while scalars *may* be stored in registers. (But my mind is a little fuzzy on the matter — I might be wrong!)

Even if you need a giant switch statement:

```
uint4 arr0123, arr4567;
uint getLUT(int x) {
    switch (x) {
    case 0: return arr0123.r0;
    case 1: return arr0123.r1;
    case 2: return arr0123.r2;
    case 3: return arr0123.r3;
    case 4: return arr4567.r0;
    case 5: return arr4567.r1;
    case 6: return arr4567.r2;
    case 7: default: return arr4567.r3;
    }
}
```

... you might still come out ahead in performance compared to a __private array, since, assuming the arr variables all fit in registers is purely ALU-bound. (Assuming you have enough spare registers for the arr variables, of course.)

Note, some OpenCL targets don't even *have* private memory, and anything you declare there just goes to __global. Using register storage is an even bigger win there.

Of course, this LUT approach is likely to be slower to initialize, since you will need at least two separate memory reads to copy the LUT data from global memory.

Comment: I had ruled out a solution like this previously because I was afraid of causing warp divergence, but I will give it a try just to see.  Why did you use 2 uint4 vectors instead of a single uint8, or just 8 variables?

Comment: This helped the performance by up to 15% ... not the 200% to 300% I was hoping for, but every bit helps.

Comment: I used uint4s because I'm an idiot. :) uint8s would be fine too I suppose. Collecting the values into a single logical variable means that you can initialize the table with vload8() instead of making (possibly) eight separate memory accesses, one for each variable. But you already knew that.

Comment: Actually, there would be next to no divergence.  Switch statements are typically implemented as arithmetic jmps (computed goto).  Because you're not doing any work in the cases, you'll diverge in *at most* one instruction, which is not bad at all.

Answer (score 1):

As rtollert stated it is up to the implementation to decide if LUT[] is placed in registers or into global memory. Normally arrays in a kernel are a no-no but since it is small it's hard to say where it will be placed. Assuming that LUT[] is placed into registers I would say the reason it's taking a long time compared to a simple arithmetic operation isn't because it's accessed randomly but because each work item makes an additional 8(Edit: apparently a lot more) global reads of X to calculate the LUT index. Depending on what's omitted could you do something like Y[i*gsi+gid] = global_table[someIndex + X[i*gsi+gid]]];?

Comment: The 8 reads from global memory are coalesced, and also outside the loop.  Since n large (around 1024 usually), the overhead of those reads to copy the LUT is effectively amortized.