# Best practices for storing a small constant-valued array in OpenCL kernel?

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I am writing an OpenCL kernel that convolves an image with a 5x5 Gaussian filter and was wondering what is the best practice for storing the filter constants. In the kernel each thread in a 32x32 workgroup does the following:

1. loads a pixel into a `__local` memory buffer,
2. sync's via `barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)`,
3. and then performs the convolution for it's corresponding pixel.

Here are the buffers for the local image data and the filter:

```
 __local float4 localRegion[32][32]; // image region w 2 pixel apron
 .... 
 static const float filter[5][5] = { // __constant vs __private ??
    {1/256.0,  4/256.0,  6/256.0,  4/256.0, 1/256.0},
    {4/256.0, 16/256.0, 24/256.0, 16/256.0, 4/256.0},
    {6/256.0, 24/256.0, 36/256.0, 24/256.0, 6/256.0},
    {4/256.0, 16/256.0, 24/256.0, 16/256.0, 4/256.0},
    {1/256.0,  4/256.0,  6/256.0,  4/256.0, 1/256.0}
  };
```

What memory regions can hold `filter`, which is best, and how does initialization occur in each case? Optimally `__private` would be best, but I am not sure you can statically initialize private array? `__local` doesn't make sense unless some of the threads are responsible for loading the `filter` entries (I think)? Also, according the the [khronos docs Sec 6.5](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-2.0-openclc.pdf), I am not sure `static` and `_private` can go together.

According to [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827381/small-array-stored-like-variables-in-a-kernel) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840720/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-small-lookup-table-in-an-opencl-kernel), `filter` can be stored as `__private` but its not clear how initialization happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but I am not sure you can statically initialize private array

Opencl spec says "The static storage-class specifier can only be used for
non-kernel functions, global variables declared in program scope and variables inside a function
declared in the global or constant address space.". On top of this, compiler(at least Amd's) optimizes constant math out and exchanges with simple (constant / instruction)memory accesses. Even on top of that, when space is not enough, private registers spill to global memory and kernel starts accessing there. So static can't have a meaningful description when real data is gone to somewhere else sometimes.

```
 float filter[5][5] = {  
    {cos(sin(cos(sin(cos(sin(1/256.0f)))))),  4/256.0f,  6/256.0f,  4/256.0f, 1/256.0f},
    {cos(sin(cos(sin(cos(sin(4/256.0f)))))), 16/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 4/256.0f},
    {sin(cos(sin(cos(sin(cos(6/256.0f)))))), 24/256.0f, 36/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 6/256.0f},
    {sin(cos(sin(cos(sin(cos(4/256.0f)))))), 16/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 4/256.0f},
    {sin(cos(sin(cos(sin(cos(1/256.0f)))))),  4/256.0f,  6/256.0f,  4/256.0f, 1/256.0f}
  };
```

takes same time(0.78ms for r7_240gpu) as

```
float filter[5][5] = { 
    {1/256.0f,  4/256.0f,  6/256.0f,  4/256.0f, 1/256.0f},
    {4/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 4/256.0f},
    {6/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 36/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 6/256.0f},
    {4/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 4/256.0f},
    {1/256.0f,  4/256.0f,  6/256.0f,  4/256.0f, 1/256.0f}
  };
```

and ISA output of profiler doesn't have any sine or cosine functions. There are just some numbers written in some memory locations. This is the condition without any optimizations enabled.

---

> What memory regions can hold filter, which is best

Depends on hardware but there are usually more than one type:

```
// defined before kernel
__constant float filter[5][5] = { 
    {1/256.0f,  4/256.0f,  6/256.0f,  4/256.0f, 1/256.0f},
    {4/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 4/256.0f},
    {6/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 36/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 6/256.0f},
    {4/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 4/256.0f},
    {1/256.0f,  4/256.0f,  6/256.0f,  4/256.0f, 1/256.0f}
  };
```

this executed in same time for a r7_240 gpu. Note that static indexing is better for `__constant` memory access(at least in amd gpu) and not bad with same-index accesses (all threads in a group access same index just like in this example(int the nested-loops)). Constant memory is faster than global memory with these addressing patterns but when varying indices are used, its not different than global memory access(even hits cache). "For globally scoped constant arrays, if the size of an array is below 64 kB, it is placed in hardware constant buffers; otherwise, it uses global memory". (There are Amd-GCN architecture related but similar behavior can be expected from Nvidia and Intel)

Amd's opencl spec says "L1 and L2 are enabled for images and same-indexed constants."(for HD5800 series gpu) So you can have similar performance using image2d_t inputs too. For GCN, L1 and L2 are faster than constant memory.

Nvidia's opencl best practices says: "p that read texture addresses that are close together will achieve best
performance. Texture memory is also designed for streaming reads with a constant
latency; that is, a cache hit reduces DRAM bandwidth demand, but not read latency.
In certain addressing situations, reading device memory through image objects can
be an advantageous alternative to reading device memory from global or constant
memory. 
" and also says "They are cached, potentially exhibiting higher bandwidth if there is 2D locality
in the texture fetches. "(image2d_t again)

You can even split filter if private memory is needed somewhere else, example:

```
// defined before kernel
__constant float filter2[3][5] = {  
    {1/256.0f,  4/256.0f,  6/256.0f,  4/256.0f, 1/256.0f},
    {4/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 4/256.0f},
    {6/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 36/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 6/256.0f},
  };

   // no need to write __private, automatically private in function body
   float filter[2][5] = { 
        {4/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 4/256.0f},
        {1/256.0f,  4/256.0f,  6/256.0f,  4/256.0f, 1/256.0f}
    };
```

this has same timings with upper two examples(at least for r7_240). All examples were run for 512x512 sized images with 512x512 workitems with 16x16 local workitems.

---

> __local doesn't make sense unless some of the threads are responsible for loading the filter entries

Local memory on Amd-GCN is 8x as fast as constant memory (same-index) accesses but has 5-20 times more capacity on whole GPU(but may be less for a single compute unit). Nvidia's opencl best practices says same. But HD5800 series amd gpu has much more constant memory bandwidth than local memory. GCN is newer so local memory seems better unless it doesn't have enough space.

Private registers on GCN is 5-6 times faster than local memory and capacity is 8 times of local memory per compute unit. So having something on private memory on GCN means ultimate performance unless that resource consumption stops enough wavefronts to launch(decreasing latency hiding).

Nvidia says similar thing too: "Generally, accessing a register consumes zero extra clock cycles per instruction, but
delays may occur due to register read-after-write dependencies and register memory
bank conflicts.
The latency of read-after-write dependencies is approximately 24 cycles, but this
latency is completely hidden on multiprocessors that have at least 192 active threads
(that is, 6 warps). 
"

---

There was also some ghost wall loading into local memory:

```
    Test gpu was r7_240 so it can work with only 16x16 local threads
    so 20x20 area is loaded from global memory.
    o: each work item's target pixel
    -: needed ghost wall because of filter going out of bounds
    x: ghost corner handled by single threads (yes,non optimized)

    xx----------------xx  
    xx----------------xx
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    --oooooooooooooooo--
    xx----------------xx  
    xx----------------xx
```

---

This kernel was used in upper profilings:

```
            __constant float filter2[3][5] = {  
                        {1/256.0f,  4/256.0f,  6/256.0f,  4/256.0f, 1/256.0f},
                        {4/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 4/256.0f},
                        {6/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 36/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 6/256.0f},
                      };


            __kernel void test1(__global uchar4 *b2,__global uchar4 *b, __global int * p)
            {
                    int j = get_local_id(0);
                    int g = get_group_id(0);
                    int gx=g%32;
                    int gy=g/32;
                    int lx=j%16;
                    int ly=j/16;
                    int x=gx*16+lx;
                    int y=gy*16+ly;
                    if(gx<2 || gx>29 || gy <2 || gy >29)
                    {
                        b2[((y * 512) + x)] = b[((y * 512) + x)];
                        return;
                    }

                    __local uchar4 localRegion[22][22]; 
                    localRegion[lx+2][ly+2]=b[((y * 512) + x)]; // interior

                    if(lx==0) // left edges
                    {   
                        localRegion[1][ly+2]=b[(( (y) * 512) + x-1)]; // x-1 edge
                        localRegion[0][ly+2]=b[(( (y) * 512) + x-2)]; // x-2 edge
                    }
                    if(lx==15) // right edges
                    {   
                        localRegion[18][ly+2]=b[(( (y) * 512) + x+1)]; // x+1 edge
                        localRegion[19][ly+2]=b[(( (y) * 512) + x+2)]; // x+2 edge
                    }

                    if(ly==0) // top edges
                    {   
                        localRegion[lx+2][1]=b[(( (y-1) * 512) + x)]; // y-1 edge
                        localRegion[lx+2][0]=b[(( (y-2) * 512) + x)]; // y-2 edge
                    }

                    if(ly==15) // bot edges
                    {   
                        localRegion[lx+2][18]=b[(( (y+1) * 512) + x)]; // y+1 edge
                        localRegion[lx+2][19]=b[(( (y+2) * 512) + x)]; // y+2 edge
                    }

                    if(lx==0 && ly==0) // upper-left square
                    {
                        localRegion[0][0]=b[(( (y-2) * 512) + x-2)];
                        localRegion[0][1]=b[(( (y-2) * 512) + x-1)];
                        localRegion[1][0]=b[(( (y-1) * 512) + x-2)];
                        localRegion[1][1]=b[(( (y-1) * 512) + x-1)];
                    }
                    if(lx==15 && ly==0) // upper-right square
                    {
                        localRegion[18][0]=b[(( (y-2) * 512) + x+1)];
                        localRegion[18][1]=b[(( (y-1) * 512) + x+1)];
                        localRegion[19][0]=b[(( (y-2) * 512) + x+2)];
                        localRegion[19][1]=b[(( (y-1) * 512) + x+2)];
                    }
                    if(lx==15 && ly==15) // lower-right square
                    {
                        localRegion[18][18]=b[(( (y+1) * 512) + x+1)];
                        localRegion[18][19]=b[(( (y+2) * 512) + x+1)];
                        localRegion[19][18]=b[(( (y+1) * 512) + x+2)];
                        localRegion[19][19]=b[(( (y+2) * 512) + x+2)];
                    }
                    if(lx==0 && ly==15) // lower-left square
                    {
                        localRegion[0][18]=b[(( (y+1) * 512) + x-2)];
                        localRegion[0][19]=b[(( (y+2) * 512) + x-2)];
                        localRegion[1][18]=b[(( (y+1) * 512) + x-1)];
                        localRegion[1][19]=b[(( (y+2) * 512) + x-1)];
                    }

                    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);



                   float filter[2][5] = { 
                        {4/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 24/256.0f, 16/256.0f, 4/256.0f},
                        {1/256.0f,  4/256.0f,  6/256.0f,  4/256.0f, 1/256.0f}
                    };


                    float4 acc=0;
                    for(int row=-2;row<=0;row++)
                        for(int col=-2;col<=2;col++)
                    {
                        uchar4 tmp=localRegion[lx+col+2][ly+row+2];
                        float tmp2=filter2[row+2][col+2];
                        acc+=((float4)(tmp2,tmp2,tmp2,tmp2)*(float4)((int)tmp.s0,(int)tmp.s1,(int)tmp.s2,(int)tmp.s3));
                    }
                    for(int row=1;row<=2;row++)
                        for(int col=-2;col<=2;col++)
                    {
                        uchar4 tmp=localRegion[lx+col+2][ly+row+2];
                        float tmp2=filter[row-1][col+2];
                        acc+=((float4)(tmp2,tmp2,tmp2,tmp2)*(float4)((int)tmp.s0,(int)tmp.s1,(int)tmp.s2,(int)tmp.s3));
                    }
                    b2[((y * 512) + x)] = (uchar4)(acc.x,acc.y,acc.z,244);
            }
```

image was 512x512 with rgba (each channel 8-bit).

Source image(but resized to 512x512 before filtering as a substep):

[image]

Result image:

[image]

Documents I referenced:

http://www.nvidia.com/content/cudazone/cudabrowser/downloads/papers/nvidia_opencl_bestpracticesguide.pdf

http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/07/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide-rev-2.7.pdf

---

Edit: if you really need __private, __local, __constant or __image2d_t  memory for something else in the kernel, you can unroll filter loop completely, delete filter array, put those araray elements in the unrolled instructions yourself(I tried, it dropped VGPR usage to 21, SGPR usage to 16)

For reference, totally elliminating filter calculation decreases execution time by 0.05 milliseconds on average while all other versions take same higher amount of time.

Comment: Wow. It's going to take me awhile to digest all of this. Amazingly thorough answer! Thank you.

Comment: Kernel had too much instructions before filtering and filtering had too many conversions between uchar4 so you can try yourself fully "float" one and maybe use %90 of threads to do a more uniform and faster local memory setup(so there wont be needed extra ghost wall loading) to see the performance gap between constant private global and local versions.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, in the `test1` kernel there is a return statement inside the first if-statement -- won't that be problematic since these threads will never reach the `barrier`? Also, why do you need the `CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE` for the barrier (I am coming from a CUDA background so I am just used to `__syncthreads()` after loading shared/local memory). Also what tools are you using to get ISA output?

Comment: @wcochran barrier comand is for workgroup. All workgroup must hit it to continue from there. In `test1`, return is reached by none(or all) of threads of a workgroup since cases are about group id.(I thinnk it has a counter inside, counting agains all threads in group only) This is why its working. If I did same for global id, it wouldnt work since 2 threads in a group wouldnt hit the barrier they had to. I'm using codexl profiler.

Comment: @wcochran you are right about CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE was not needed here. It is slowing the kernel. Only local memory is altered here.